# Link between matrix nodes not horizontal

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, links, tikz-matrix

I'm using tikz matrix to put some data on a grid. However depending on the height of what's in each node the edge linking two nodes are slightly slanted making an ugly effect of wavy line. How can I have those line straight ?

Here is an example of code generating the effect

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, wasysym}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
% tikz environnement
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, snakes, shapes, arrows, arrows.meta, matrix, calc, graphs,
  plotmarks, backgrounds, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick,
  column sep={1.5cm,between origins}, row sep={1.0cm,between origins}]
  \matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes, nodes={inner sep=1pt}] {
  U_1 & \cdots & U_{i-1} & U_{i-1} \cup \{i\} & U_{i-1}^\sharp &
  U_{i}^\sharp & \cdots & U_{N} \\
};
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,7} {
    \draw[thin] (M-1-\n.east) -- (M-1-\the\numexpr \n + 1\relax.west);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

And here is what I get:
[image: Wavy row]

I tried to fix the height of the node but it doesn't work. I also tried a trick such as [tikz matrix arrow from empty nodes is not horizontal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327138/tikz-matrix-arrow-from-empty-nodes-is-not-horizontal) should do the work, but if possible, I would like to avoid inserting by hand some phantom text in front of each node (moreover such a text add some horizontal spacing).

Comment: A `matrix of nodes` fixes anchor nodes to `base`, you have to hange them to `center`: `nodes={inner sep=1pt, anchor=center}`

Comment: Just a `\mathstrut` would probably be enough. And you can use `execute at begin node=\mathstrut` to let TikZ do it automatically for you. For more complex nodes you can use [node families](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121054) so that TikZ chooses the right maximum height and depth for all nodes. Though, the best solution would be to use the `asymmetric rectangle` shape from TikZ-CD. This is exactly why the shape exists. (It sets the west/center/east anchor a fixed but variable distance from the baseline.)

Comment: @ignasi This totally works ! Thank you.

Comment: You can also just do `([yshift=.5ex]M-1-\n.base east) -- ([yshift=.5ex]M-1-\the\numexpr \n + 1\relax.base west)`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to draw the border of the nodes or fill them you can use the `asymmetrical rectangle` shape from TikZ-CD. This shape is made exactly for this reason.

In fact, the same diagram can be made just as easy with TikZ-CD.

The shape is set up so that the west/center/east anchor is a fixed but variable distance above the baseline. This distance is controlled the value of `/tikz/commutative diagrams/center yshift` which defaults to `axis_height`, a PGFMath function that returns

> the axis height parameter (a.k.a. *σ*₂₂) of the document's math font.

Or in layman's terms: Where we want it for typesetting math content.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, wasysym}
% tikz environnement
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, matrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ultra thick,
  column sep={1.5cm,between origins},
  row sep={1.0cm,between origins}]
\matrix (M) [
  matrix of math nodes,
  nodes={inner sep=1pt, asymmetrical rectangle},
]{
  U_1 & \cdots & U_{i-1} & U_{i-1} \cup \{i\} & U_{i-1}^\sharp &
  U_{i}^\sharp & \cdots & U_{N} \\
};
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,7}
  \draw[thin] (M-1-\n.east) -- (M-1-\the\numexpr \n + 1\relax.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  arrows=dash, cells={nodes={inner sep=1pt}},
  column sep={1.5cm,between origins}, row sep={1cm,between origins}]
U_1 \rar & \cdots \rar & U_{i-1} \rar
  & U_{i-1} \cup \{i\} \rar & U_{i-1}^\sharp \rar
  & U_{i}^\sharp \rar & \cdots \rar & U_{N}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]